# Is there a stable and secure CMS that makes it easy (through docs and community) to write plugins/modules?

Tags: web-applications, content-management-system

I'm thinking about building a website to have some kind of public facing content, but at the same time, I would like to be able to build modules and plugins without too much of a hassle. I'm looking at things like Wordpress, Joomla, and Drupal, but I'm wondering if anyone has personal experience in using and (more specifically) developing for these applications.

**Personally, I'm looking for something in PHP, but if you know of one in another language, feel free to post it to help someone else who is looking for something similar in language X/Y/Z.**

Answer (score 6):

I would highly recommend [Drupal](http://www.drupal.org) (http://www.drupal.org). It is very stable and highly secure CMS system. In addition to being a CMS, it is part a PHP Framework.

Drupal Extentions/Plugins are called Modules. These modules allows you use Drupal API to do almost anything a framework like CodeIgniter or CakePHP does.

Drupal Framework portion already includes common things like User Registration, Access Control Based on Roles and Permissions, Error Logging System, Pagination, Database Abstraction and Templates etc.

Additionally, Drupal is a full fledged CMS with UI to do lot of extreme things. Many many major companies have started using Drupal as their CMS i.e. [The Onion](http://www.theonion.com)

Comment: I think it is better to call it CMS + Framework rather than CMS Framework. I find terminology CMS Framework confusing ... What does that even suppose to mean?

Answer (score 2):

[Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/).
It has a great community, very good docs, really easy to learn and you start being productive immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend pmwiki (http://www.pmwiki.org/)

It's highly customizable, written in PHP, it's easy to write your own modules, and it has a full security system.

Answer (score 0):

[Immediacy](http://www.immediacy.co.uk/) is one to consider. This system is targeted at .Net though.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what kind of modules you want to write. For example, WordPress has a plugins feature which is great for extending parts of the model, but it's really locked into "The Loop" for displaying content. Wordpress is pretty much tied to the posts+pages system, (posts are blogs, pages is a hierarchy)

You might also consider a wiki.

So, what kind of modules do you want to write that you haven't seen in existing CMS tools?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend SPIP.  This is a highly customizable CMS with quite a number of plug-ins. it's codes are written in French and hackers have no chance to access any codes.
Just visit http://www.spip.net

Havaths

Comment: No French speaking hackers?